# SQL Query (or Join) for 3 tables

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

first time asking a question on Stack Overflow... Amazing resource, but there's just one thing that's really baffling me as a newcomer to SQL.

I have three tables and I would like to obtain the names of all the Mentors who are linked to Bob's students.

Table 1: TEACHERS

```
================
ID     Name
================
1     Bob
```

Table 2: STUDENTS

```
===================================
STUDENT_ID     Name     TEACHER_ID
===================================
1              Jayne    1
2              Billy    5
3              Mark     2
```

Table 3: MENTOR_RELATIONSHIPS

```
==============================
ID     STUDENT_ID    MENTOR_ID
==============================
1      1             3
2      2             2
3      3             3
```

Table 4: MENTORS

```
=====================
MENTOR_ID     Name  
=====================
1            Sally
2            Gillian
3            Sean
```

I would like to run a query to find all of the mentors of Bob's students.  So the mentors for all students with `TEACHER_ID = 1`

In this case Sean would be the result.

I know that it is something to do with Joins, or could I find this using a normal query??

Any help is much appreciated!  Many thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this should do the work

```
select distinct m.name from students s
inner join mentor_ralationships mr on mr.student_id=s.student_id
inner join mentors m on m.mentoir_id=mr.mentor_id
where s.teacher_id=1;
```

Comment: Thank you for this :-)  I'll try it in a second, but to help me understand the code, what is purpose of the initials `m` in `m.name`?  Is it shorthand?  Or a variable??  Similarly `s` in `students s` and `mr` in `mr.mentor_id`...?

Thank you!

Comment: it is alias for the table m instead "mentor" s instead "students" and mr instead "mentor_ralationships" aliases are very usefull in complex join queries

Comment: Just to say this works a charm, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: How will you show only selected field from those tables i.e. T.ID, T.Name, S.ID, S.Name, M.ID, M.Name? Thank you.

Comment: I got the solution this way...select s.ID as StudentID, s.Name as StudentName, mr.ID as MentorID, mr.Name as MentorName from students s
inner join mentor_ralationships mr on mr.student_id=s.student_id
inner join mentors m on m.mentoir_id=mr.mentor_id
where s.teacher_id=1;

Answer (score 0):

Without joins (not preferred)

```
SELECT mentors.name FROM mentors 
WHERE mentors.id 
  IN (SELECT MENTOR_RELATIONSHIPS.mentor FROM  MENTOR_RELATIONSHIPS 
  WHERE  MENTOR_RELATIONSHIPS.student 
    IN (SELECT students.id FROM students WHERE students.teacher 
        = (SELECT teachers.id FROM teachers WHERE teachers.name = 'bob')));
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be helpful for you as I had to retrieve data from three tables `AssignedSubject, Section and SchoolClass` when a teacher assigned to specific subject then I have to find out the his class and section details including subjectid which I did this way

```
select a.StaffID, a.SubjectID, s.ID as SectionId, s.Name as SectionName, S.Remarks as SectionRemarks, sc.ID as ClassId, sc.Name as ClassName, sc.Remarks as ClassRemarks from AssignedSubject a
     inner join Section s on a.SectionId=s.ID 
     inner join SchoolClass sc on sc.ID=s.ClassId  where a.StaffID=3068
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.name
FROM students s INNER JOIN TEACHERS t ON t.ID = a.TEACHER_ID
  INNER JOIN MENTOR_RELATIONSHIPS mr ON mr.Student_id = s.Student_id
  INNER JOIN Mentors m ON mr.MENTOR_ID = s.MENTOR_ID
WHERE s.teacher_id = 1   WHERE t.Name = 'Bob';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TEACHER.NAME, STUDENTS.NAME AS STUDENT NAME, MENTORS.NAME AS MENTOR 
FROM TEACHERS JOIN STUDENTS ON TEACHERS.ID = STUDENTS.TEACHER_ID 
              JOIN MENTOR_RELATIONSHIPS ON STUDENTS.STUDENT_ID = 
                   MENTOR_RELATIONSHIPS.STUDENT_ID 
              JOIN MENTORS ON MENTOR_RELATIONSHIPS.MENTOR_ID = MENTORS.MENTOR_ID 
WHERE TEACHER.NAME = 'Bob' ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!