# How to query from three tables like this

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have three table project, client and work. Like this

Project Table

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|   project_id  |   project_name    |   client_id       |
---------------------------------------------------------
|       1       |       abc         |       1           |
|       2       |       xyz         |       2           |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Client Table

```
-------------------------------------
|   client_id   |   client_name     |
-------------------------------------
|       1       |       a           |
|       2       |       b           |
-------------------------------------
```

work table

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|   work_id     |       work_cost   |   project_id      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|       1       |       100         |       1           |
|       2       |       200         |       1           |
|       3       |       100         |       2           |
|       4       |       100         |       1           |
|       5       |       100         |       1           |
|       6       |       200         |       2           |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Here I want to query from three table like this and display the result.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   project_id  |   project_name    |   client_name |   total_work_cost |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1       |       abc         |       a       |       500         |
|       2       |       xyz         |       b       |       300         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here total_work_cost means, suppose project 1 has 4 record in work table. I want to sum all of the work_cost from work table of project 1.

I have tried like this-

```
SELECT project.*, c.client_name, SUM(w.work_cost) as total_work_cost
    FROM project
    LEFT JOIN client as c ON project.client_id = c.client_id
    INNER JOIN work as w on project.project_id = w.project_id
    ORDER BY projects.project_id
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query (or Join) for 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642616/sql-query-or-join-for-3-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing aggregation logic i.e. GROUP BY clause in your query:

```
SELECT p.project_id, p.project_name, c.client_name, SUM(w.work_cost) as total_work_cost
FROM project as p LEFT JOIN client as c 
ON p.client_id = c.client_id
LEFT JOIN work as w 
on p.project_id = w.project_id
GROUP BY p.project_id, p.project_name, c.client_name
ORDER BY p.project_id
```

Comment: Thanks. working fine. But why I have to use GROUP BY in that case?

Comment: Because you want to use SUM i.e. aggregate function.